# Анимация в слайдере

Tags: jquery, slider, анимация, javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Не подскажите, как реализовать такую штуку:

1. Имеем слайдер, где на одном **слайде
       находятся три элемента** (div
       например).
2. Этот слайдер листает сразу
       по 3 элемента, получается по одному слайду
       (1 слайд =(содержит) 3 элементам).

Так вот, как сделать анимацию при пролистывании, подобную такому описанию:

1. Эти три элемента на активном слайде как бы друг за другом уходят, например влево.
2. Тогда справа выезжают новые три элемента друг за другом, паравозиком. )))

Причем именно друг за другом, т.е. сначала видим первый элемент слайда, **немного погодя**  за ним второй... когда первый достигает конца и останавливается, **второй еще едет** до своего места. => Получается, что анимация как бы применяется с задержкой к каждому элементу слайда.

Как стек или шарики в лунку, закатываем: 1 едет стоп - 2-й едет стоп (около первого). (Причем второй появляется, когда первый не достиг конца и какой-то момент времени они оба на слайде двигаются к конечной позиции.)

Может, есть уже готовый слайдер с такой реализацией? Я не прошу готовый код, просто алгоритм/подход, как это сделать!

Comment: Вам нужен метод `.pause()`, который добавляет паузу в анимации. Конкретное время можно рассчитывать через [разница во времени у соседних элементов] * [индекс элемента].

Comment: Миллион вариантов, к примеру, можно "навешывать" класс на активный слайд, и в нём прописать порядок отображения элементов внутри этого слайда, при помощи css animations, или скажем transition-delay.

Comment: Я нашел, что имел ввиду - http://yootheme.com/demo/themes/joomla/2011/shelf/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=19&Itemid=77

Первый слайдер (Slide Example).

Вот так же хочу сделать, только САМ!
Идею с css-animation понял, там как раз и transform и delay удобный, вроде как!

Comment: CSS с этим легко справится, удачи!